# How can you retreive specific strings from a list, specifically strings that start with a certain letter in C#?

Tags: c#, string, linq

My c# code looks like this. I want find names starting with a particular letter using LINQ or anything else.

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name {0}", count++);
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            list.Add(name);
        }
        foreach (var n in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to come up with a solution ? For instance, search how you find that a string starts with a specific letter. There is a method for this you can find by a bit googling. Having such a method, would help you to solve your problem.

Comment: In your `foreach`, the varialbe `n` is the string.  To get the first character of the string use `n[0]`.  Then compare that against the letter you need.

Comment: @Ferrad, Did you have any luck figuring out your issue?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-2.0) method and the [StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netcore-2.0) Method
`list.Where(x=>x.StartsWith('a'))`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want, you can either use the `Where` clause:

```
var result = list.Where(n => n.StartsWith("m", StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

or only add the names which starts with a particular letter:

```
if(name.StartsWith("m", StringComparison.Ordinal))
       list.Add(name);
```

The latter example means you don't add names to the accumulating list which do not start with a given letter, hence you don't have to filter alter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var n in list.Where(n => n.StartsWith("m")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: Can't edit because it is less than 6 characters but should name be n?